# Everytime I call :Explore netrw creates a new unlisted buffer

Tags: buffers, netrw, hidden-buffers

[image]

Is there any way to stay always in the same netrw buffer after selecting a file to edit?

Answer (score 1):

Netrw already includes [code that attempts to reuse buffers](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim#L4156) but, as you have discovered, this code currently appears not to handle tree listings and ends up creating many buffers.

So the first thing to try is to make sure you are using the latest version of netrw. It looks like the code has changed as recently as July 2019, so it's possible this is something that has been fixed.

If that fails, however, and presuming you're not planning on altering the netrw plugin itself, your options include:

1. Stop using `g:netrw_liststyle = 3`. In netrw's other list styles the buffers are named simply after the directory they display, and far fewer of them are created.
2. Stop using *netrw*. It's possible that [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) or [dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish/) (which doesn't currently support tree views, but [has them on the roadmap](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish/issues/70#issuecomment-273187435)) don't exhibit this issue.
3. Note that the buffers aren't listed in `ls`, so if you can refrain from using the `:ls!` version of the command maybe you can kid yourself that they don't exist at all.
4. If option 3. is unpalatable, perhaps you can live with the fact that the buffers are *created*, but [get them to remove themselves when they are hidden](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/13). This should be as simple as setting `bufhidden=wipe` for each netrw buffer with a simple `autocmd FileType` (as suggested on the linked page), but at least on my machine, `netrw` itself overwrites `bufhidden`, so some shenanigans may be required. This code worked for me:

   ```
   function! WipeBuffer(name, id)
     let buffer_number = bufnr(a:name)
     execute 'bwipeout' buffer_number
   endfunction

   augroup WipeNetrw
     autocmd!
     autocmd BufHidden * if &ft == 'netrw' | call timer_start(100, function('WipeBuffer', [expand('<afile>')])) | endif
   augroup END
   ```

Comment: Can't believe I'm the only upvote on this solid, well researched answer.

Comment: @BLayer I appreciate the sentiment. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. The voting patterns here in Vi/Vim SE baffle me sometimes, this being a glowing (glaring?) example, so I felt compelled to comment (maybe the activity will bump it into view of some voters...haha. :P )